# Excel change cell color

Tags: excel

Just to confirm that this is NOT JUST conditional formatting! I'm using Excel 2010.

I have used http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx ColorIndexOfOneCell function, but it doesnt seem to identify the Conditionally Formatted cell colors. The following code has been used, with the relevant cell color in C89:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(colorindex(L6:L82)=ColorIndexOfOneCell($C$89,FALSE,1)))
```

Any ideas?

PS. When manually changing the cell colors ("behind" the conditional formatting), ColorIndexOfCell DOES pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "excel conditional formatting color applied vba"  yields a link: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cfcolors.htm  (heay same source). It suggests checking with their `ActiveCondition` script.

Or alternatively: "vba excel check active condition" yields an alternative code on this page:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1409-excel-vba-a-function-that-returns-the-color-of-an-active-mfc
Even more elegant.

Both come down to looping through possible `FormatConditions` and then checking in the script if the condition is met. When the condition is met the color of that condition is taken.